# makeTouchBar() not being called Mac Catalyst touchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mac-catalyst

hoping you can help, I'm going a bit mad with this. I have an Objective-c iOS project I am porting over top MacOS using Catalyst. All has been going well until I have got to adding Touchbar support.

I have a swift extension of my main viewController, in which I am implementing the required delegate methods for NSTouchBarDelegate

Problem is, `makeTouchBar`is never called, either in the Swift extension :

```
@objc override open func makeTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar? {
     let touchBar = NSTouchBar()
      touchBar.delegate = self
      touchBar.defaultItemIdentifiers = [...identifiers...]
      return touchBar
    }
```

or just in the original Obj-C viewController :

```
- (NSTouchBar *)makeTouchBar {
    return ...;
}
```

I've followed multiple tutorials which all basically say 'override makeTouchBar and it will all magically work'. I am successfully adding Toolbars and Menu's to the app, so I'm a bit stumped what's going on and why this method is never getting called by the system.

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers
Emile

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which caused by my SceneDelegate implementing NSTouchBarDelegate. Instead, I should have had my AppDelegate implementing NSTouchBarDelegate.

Here is a working example to add a Touchbar to a SwiftUI Catalyst 13.0 app:

```swift
//
//  TouchbarDelegate.swift
//  TenderHub
//
//  Created by Peter Chapman on 5/08/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Conglomo Limited. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
extension NSTouchBarItem.Identifier {
    static let play = NSTouchBarItem.Identifier("play")
    static let trash = NSTouchBarItem.Identifier("trash")
}

extension AppDelegate: NSTouchBarDelegate {
    
    override func makeTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar? {
        let touchBar = NSTouchBar()
        touchBar.delegate = self
        
        touchBar.defaultItemIdentifiers = [
            .flexibleSpace,
            .play,
            .trash,
            .flexibleSpace
        ]
        
        return touchBar
    }
    
    func touchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar, makeItemForIdentifier identifier: NSTouchBarItem.Identifier) -> NSTouchBarItem? {
        let touchBarItem: NSTouchBarItem?
        
        switch identifier {
        case .play:
            guard let image = UIImage(systemName: "play") else { return nil }
            touchBarItem = NSButtonTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier,
                                                image: image,
                                                target: UIApplication.shared.openSessions.first?.scene?.delegate,
                                                action: #selector(SceneDelegate.play(_:)))
            
        case .trash:
            guard let image = UIImage(systemName: "trash") else { return nil }
            touchBarItem = NSButtonTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier,
                                                image: image,
                                                target: UIApplication.shared.openSessions.first?.scene?.delegate,
                                                action: #selector(SceneDelegate.trash(_:)))
        default:
            touchBarItem = nil
        }
        
        return touchBarItem
    }
}
#endif
```